# How to capture PHPUnit command-line output?

Tags: php, testing, model-view-controller, controller, phpunit

[image]

Writing a unit test to my index controller, i need to capture the html exit from the console into an array or string in order to test it.

But i have no idea how to capture the exit from my phpunit console.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: This can be done with ob_start and ob_get_clean. This will grab the output buffer to a string and you can store it elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to John comment about ob_get_clean i got the thing done like that:

```
$userController = new Application\controllers\User;
ob_start();     
$userController->index();       
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo "Output: " . $output;
```